# Loading a XIB file to a UIView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, xib

I am trying to load my `XIB` file into a `UIView` but I am having some trouble. I have the required override functions but they seem to be crashing. Saying this error, warning:

> could not load any Objective-C class information. This will
>   significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

I was wondering if someone could show me how to properly load the `XIB` file into a `UIView`

```
import UIKit

class Widget: UIView {

    let view = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        //call function

        loadNib()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        loadNib()

        //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func loadNib() {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "nib", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(view);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your XIB file really named "nil"?

Comment: Seems to work fine...which specific line is it crashing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load a UIView from nib in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857986/load-a-uiview-from-nib-in-swift)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I uses this in one of our projects, might be useful to you

```
import UIKit

class RegisterPageView: UIView {
    
        class func instanceFromNib() -> RegisterPageView {
            return UINib(nibName: "RegisterPageView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! RegisterPageView
        }
}
```

Comment: It not works with  `thisView.alpha = 0` , `thisView.superview`

Answer (score 23):

Using Swift 3.0

```
let viewFromNib: UIView? = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NibName", 
    owner: nil, 
    options: nil)?.first
```

Answer (score 18):

Improved [DevAndArtist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43123783/770081%20%22DevAndArtist) UIView extension

```
public extension UIView
{
    static func loadFromXib<T>(withOwner: Any? = nil, options: [UINib.OptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> T where T: UIView
    {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "\(self)", bundle: bundle)

        guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: withOwner, options: options).first as? T else {
            fatalError("Could not load view from nib file.")
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let view = CustomView.loadFromXib()
let view = CustomView.loadFromXib(withOwner: self)
let view = CustomView.loadFromXib(withOwner: self, options: [UINibExternalObjects: objects])
```

[External Objects discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143606/object-vs-external-object-in-xcode-interface-builder)

Answer (score 14):

Here is my approach (written in Swift 3.1):

```
protocol XibDesignable : class {}

extension XibDesignable where Self : UIView {

    static func instantiateFromXib() -> Self {

        let dynamicMetatype = Self.self
        let bundle = Bundle(for: dynamicMetatype)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "\(dynamicMetatype)", bundle: bundle)

        guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? Self else {

            fatalError("Could not load view from nib file.")
        }
        return view
    }
}

extension UIView : XibDesignable {}
```

Now I simply can create any UIView subclass from a Xib (assuming there is one) like so `MyCustomView.instantiateFromXib()`. Remember to name your Xib file exactly as your `UIView` subclass and set the type of the main view in that Xib file correctly.

---

As soon as [SE-0068](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md) will be implemented one could drop the protocol and move the function directly into the `UIView` extension.

---

Just a note: The original post uses a commonly used pattern with a nested view. IMHO this is a bad pattern which does not utilize the resources and only creates unnecessary view hierarchy.

Comment: I like this approach. In my case, .xib files contain only one view of the current class and `guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).last` crashed, since `.last` returned nil. 

For some reason, `guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0]` works great though. Just change `.last` to `[0]`

Comment: There is no `.last` in my sample. Furthermore `.first` cannot be nil if the array really contains something. `[0]` will also crash if the array is empty.

Comment: @DevAndArtist I have used your code and I'm facing a memory leak issue.

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4.x**

```
let myView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("yourXibView", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
```

Answer (score 7):

for **swift 3**

```
class YourClass:  UIView {
    class func instanceFromNib() -> YourClass {
        return UINib(nibName: "YourClassNibName", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! YourClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you fill some more blanks in? Where does that go and where does it get called? I've been mucking around with this longer than I care to admit and everything I've found is either out of date Swift or Objective-C. Seems like it's a simple exercise, but I'm too ****ing dumb to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

In my project I implemented the following (very similar to Peter's Solution)

```
import UIKit

// MARK: - Protocol Declaration

public protocol InterfaceBuilderInstantiable
{
    /// The UINib that contains the view
    ///
    /// Defaults to the swift class name if not implemented
    static var associatedNib : UINib { get }
}

// MARK: - Default Implementation

extension InterfaceBuilderInstantiable
{
    /// Creates a new instance from the associated Xib
    ///
    /// - Returns: A new instance of this object loaded from xib
    static func instantiateFromInterfaceBuilder() -> Self
    {
        return associatedNib.instantiate(withOwner:nil, options: nil)[0] as! Self
    }

    static var associatedNib : UINib
    {
        let name = String(describing: self)
        return UINib(nibName: name, bundle: Bundle.main)
    }
}
```

To use, you just simply implement the protocol:

```
class MyView: UIView, InterfaceBuilderInstantiable
{
    // The rest
```

And if your nib is the same name as your class (`MyView.xib`), you're set:  the default implementation of the protocol looks for a nib with the same name as the class in the main bundle.

Of course, if your nib is in another bundle or has a different name you can override the `associatedNib` and return your own nib.

Comment: I have used your approach but it leads to memory leak in the App.

Answer (score 3):

Usually I use the following way to load a xib file owned by a custom `UIView`:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: self, options: nil)[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.x

This is finally how I did it
This is not in the customView itself. I put the code where the ViewController is loading the customView.

```
import UIKit

class StartMenuViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customView: CustomView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
        customView .addSubview(myView)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let xibView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NameXibView", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.x**

```
let loadMusicView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MusicView", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as? MusicView
loadMusicView?.frame = controlsMainView.bounds
loadMusicView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
controlsMainView.addSubview(loadMusicView!)

//if you have variables in your .xib file access those variables like this
loadMusicView.yourVariableName = .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share this piece of code that required me some effort to make it resilient.

```
import Foundation

protocol Nib {

    func registerNib()

}

extension Nib where Self : UIView {

    func registerNib() {
        guard let nibName = type(of: self).description().components(separatedBy: ".").last else { return }
        // ** Check if resource is used in Interface Builder first to avoid crash during compile
        #if !TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        guard let _ = bundle.path(forResource: nibName, ofType: "nib")
            else { fatalError("can't find \(nibName) xib resource in current bundle") }
        #endif
        guard let view = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView
            else { return }
        // ** Another way to write it but do not work if xib is bundled with framework
        //guard let view = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
        //    else { return }
        view.frame = bounds
        addSubview(view)
    }

}
```

You can use this as follow creating a xib resource file named as class name (aka CustomView.xib)

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView, Nib {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        postInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        postInit()
    }

    func postInit() {
        registerNib()
    }

}
```

Do not forget to set xib resource file's owner class to CustomView and leave blank custom class class field.

Answer (score 0):

//**Just use this class as super class for the view **

```
import UIKit

class ViewWithXib: UIView {

func initUI() {}

private func xibSetup() {
    let view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
    initUI()
}

private func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let thisName = String(describing: type(of: self))
    let view = Bundle(for: self.classForCoder).loadNibNamed(thisName, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
    return view
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
}

}
```

// Usage

```
class HeaderView: ViewWithXib {
}


let header = HeaderView() // No need to load the view from nib, It will work
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  func configureNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomUIView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}
```

And use this tutorial for custom view with xib...
https://developerfly.com/custom-view-use-xib-swift/