# Nil Enherited outlet on the subclass

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I've defined a base class with an outlet and attached the outlet to the view in the nib file

```
class BaseController: UIViewController  {


@IBOutlet weak var myView : UIView!

and then created a subclass 

class SubViewController: BaseController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red //The app crashes here
```

When i call `BaseController()` it view appears, but when I call `SubViewController()` the app crashes because `myView` is nil. The files owner on the nib file is BaseController.

Comment: Use  `SubViewController.init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?)`

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. Is it possible to use a nib file that contain a UIView with different viewController, to allow each controller fraw something different in the view?

Comment: How did you `init` your `SubViewController`? The thing is since the super class have a `IBOutlet` linked in a Xib, you have to the parent with the xib to be able to use the IBOulet. Same for the children.

Comment: @J.Doe You should init your view controller with nib file. So you should use method that was mentioned above. `SubViewController.init(nibName: "Here should be name of your nib file", bundle: nil)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to create custom initializer in your subclass:

```
init() {
    super.init(nibName: "BaseController", bundle: nil)
}
```

Comment: Can this same approach be done with a UIView rather than a ViewController?

Comment: @Chucky No. Loading `UIView` from xib is done a little bit different. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35666644/4646572.

Comment: Thanks! And can I share the outlets of the base class this way? ie Baseview : UIView, Subview : BaseView